# Eclipse Console is not running for Scanner / User input operation

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output, java.util.scanner

When i click run button on eclipse, its console is not running like it does for usual programs. my guess is that there is some issues because of "Scanner" class.

```
import java.util.*;
public class CandidateCode {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        //System.out.println("inside main");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("enter string : ");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(input);
        System.in.close();

        CandidateCode cc = new CandidateCode();
        System.out.println(cc.logic(input));
    }

    public String logic(String input) {

        String newLine= System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String output = "Hello Techgig"+newLine+ input;

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: This runs fine here. Are you sure you are running this program? What does the Console actually show?

Comment: it works. Try closing the Scanner instead of System.in